# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This code used to work it still works if I have a certain excel file but with my excel it doesn't work. I guess it is issue with the version but not sure. even all the cells are in text format because the data needed to be in string format

```
TestExcelReader xlreader = new TestExcelReader();
String inputFilePath = "/C:/ExcelData/Test1 (2).xlsx";
List<TestInputBook> listinputBooks = xlreader.readBooksFromExcelFile(inputFilePath);
{
    TestBook bookobj = new TestBook(receipt.getReceiptId(),receipt.getTxnNumber(),receipt.getMessage(),receipt.getAuthCode(),receipt.getIssuerId(),Msg,receipt.getCavvResultCode(),"","","");
    try
    {
        listBook.add(bookobj);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
TestExcelWriter xlwriter = new TestExcelWriter();
String excelFilePath = "/C:/ExcelData/Automate1Output.xlsx";        
xlwriter.writeExcel(listBook, excelFilePath);
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the entire stack trace from the exception, explain what you're trying to do, and how you've tried to fix your own problem.

Comment: The question is that it doesn't take data from excel file and throw this error

Comment: your hashtable listBook is null. but we do not see the initialisation of it

Comment: Is your file called Test1 (2).xlsx and is it inside C:/ExcelData ?

Comment: The error is thrown from `TestExcelReader.readBooksFromExcelFile`. But you are not showing that code. So no help possible. I suspect the method `readBooksFromExcelFile` does not handling empty cells properly.